# Cardview with Gridlayout produce unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, android-viewpager, grid-layout, android-cardview

I am using a `GridLayout` inside of an `CardView` and then loading the layouts in a `ViewPager` but when I slide the layout in viewpager then cardview has these corners which are not rounded

[image: Image of the error]

What might be the problem?
Here is the XML code for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
grid:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        grid:columnCount="5"
        grid:rowCount="6">

        <!-- Row 1-->
        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            grid:layout_column="0"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="1"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="1"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="1"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text="%"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="2"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="1"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="3"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="1"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />


        <!-- Row 2-->
        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="0"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="2"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="1"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="2"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="2"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="2"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="3"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="2"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <!-- Row 3-->
        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="0"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="3"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="1"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="3"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="2"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="3"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="3"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="3"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <!-- Row 4-->
        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="0"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="4"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="1"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="4"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="2"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="4"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="3"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="4"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <!-- Row 5-->
        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="0"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="5"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="1"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="5"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcNumber"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="2"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="5"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/calcAction"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            grid:layout_column="3"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
            grid:layout_row="5"
            grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: it would great if you mark the answer as correct if it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius
```

Instead of

```
grid:cardCornerRadius
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.
Since I have declared the namespace as `grid` therefore so I used that.
When I add a namespace for `card_view` then rounded corners are not made

Comment: what namespace did you add for cardview?

Comment: what output did you get?

Comment: Same output, since both the namespaces are same, there is no issue of namespace I think

Comment: can you add the image of output of complete card not only the upper part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173278/discussion-between-nishant-and-yugansh-tyagi).

Comment: have you closed the cardview tag because cant see the closing tag in your code